# How to create an objects collection from two arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm using Laravel and i have two arrays in a controller

```
$country_name=["italia", "japan", "congo", "uk"]
$country_capital=["roma", "tokyo", "kinshasa", "london"]
```

Please note that the position of the country name in `$country_name` array is the same as the corresponding capital in the `$country_capital` array.

From these two arrays, I'm looking for a way to create a collection of objects called `$countries`, so in my blade file I could be able to use it like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($countries as $country)
       <li>{{$country->country_name}} : {{$country->country_capital}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

If someone can help me with functions or steps to obtain `$countries` from the two given arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$country_name = ["italia", "japan", "congo", "uk"];
$country_capital = ["roma", "tokyo", "kinshasa", "london"];

$countries = array_map(function ($countryName, $countryCapital) {
    return [
        'country_name' => $countryName,
        'country_capital' => $countryCapital,
    ];
}, $country_name, $country_capital);

dd(collect($countries));
```

Answer (score 4):

providing your keys match you could do:

```
$foo = collect([
    'country_name'    => $country_name,
    'country_capital' => $country_capital
]);
```

which would return:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1966
     all: [
       "country_name" => [
         "italia",
         "japan",
         "congo",
         "uk",
       ],
       "country_capital" => [
         "roma",
         "tokyo",
         "kinshasa",
         "london",
       ],
     ],
   }
```

if your keys don't match you will need to do something with the arrays before you merge them. I also tested this quickly in artisan tinker so don't take this as final.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
    $obj=new stdClass();
    $country_name=["italia", "japan", "congo", "uk"];
    $country_capital=["roma", "tokyo", "kinshasa", "london"];
    $obj=(object)array_combine ($country_name , $country_capital );
    var_dump($obj);

   ?>
```

You can get key as country name and value as capital.

Answer (score 0):

in php
You could use aforeach over two array

```
foreach($country_name as $key => $value ){
  $countries[$key]['name'] = $value;
  $countries[$key]['capital'] = $country_capital[$key];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$country_name=["italia", "japan", "congo", "uk"];
$country_capital=["roma", "tokyo", "kinshasa", "london"];

$i=0; 

?>

<ul>
     @foreach($country_name as $country)
        <li>{{$country_name[$i]}} : {{$country_capital[$i]}}</li>
       <?php $i++; ?>
       @endforeach

</ul>
```

Try it. as simple as easy to understand